# Enable Resource Governor

Tags: performance, sql, central-processing-unit, throttling

I have setup an SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 in my infrastructure. One of my SQL jobs consumes much CPU usage and when this happens all other queries take too long to respond.

After research I read about Resource Governor. This feature throttles CPU usage for defined resources. I have two questions after all information I have found:

- Does SQL server or SQL agent needs restart to be enabled?
- How can I configure Resource Governor for only one SQL job?